# Queries with intersections between partitions

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE videos_by_tags (
    tag text,
    video_id uuid,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY ((tag) video_id)
)
```

which will support queries such as `get videos by tagA`. If in the future I need to support queries like `get videos by tagA and tabB and tagC`, how would I set up my cassandra tables?

Is there a specific way to set up tables for this scenario, or do I have to query in a specific way?

Or would I have to resort to grabbing an x of amount of results for each tag criteria (ie: 100 items from `tagA`, 100 items from `tagB`, etc) and manually determine the same, unique items from each set?